# Loading private key (missing bitcoin)

Tags: blockchain, wallet, private-key-import

I exported the private key from a 0.7.2 because I could not how to upgrade the wallet.  I then imported it into 0.18.0 I was expecting to see a  balance and the transactions and nothing was found.  I also searched the blockchain through blockchain.com using the public address from the original wallet and again found nothing.  Would greatly appreciate advice

Comment: Can you post the address here? Perhaps it is an old address, that held some of your coins at one point, but no longer does? Are you familiar with what a 'change address' is?

Answer (score 1):

If you have bitcoins in any address, they should be there unless someone else got access to your wallet and stole them, in which case you should see in a block explorer the corresponding transaction.